# How do i put text ontop of my navbar background images?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to put text ontop of my navbar, but wherever i place the text such as "Home" it appears either bellow or ontop of my actual navbar.

[this is how it looks in my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz6zZ.png)

[And this is what i want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9EqF.png)

and this is my html code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-AU-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Main page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f96187f2fa.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="nav_image.png" alt="">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="nav_image.png" alt="" >
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="nav_image.png" alt="" >
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="nav_image.png" alt="" >
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my css code

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #D0FEFE;
  margin: 30px 50px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.main-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.1rem;

}



.main-nav img {
width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: can you add link to website?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a CSS property called `z-index`. You can find more information on how to use `z-index` at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp), and they also have a helpful [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex).

Answer (score 0):

1) As you may see, there are no links at all in your HTML file, just images.
So, first of all, insert the link you want in each list item.

```
<li> <a href="link"> Home </a></li>
```

You may find how to manipulate links here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Instead of putting the images as elements in HTML, insert them as backgrounds of the list items in CSS.

```
ul li{
background-image: url("Your image");
}
```

You can manipulate the background-size the way you want. Just follow these instructions https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Answer (score 0):

I added two CSS selectors: `box` and `textbox`. `box`-div for around each image and `textbox`-div under each image for the text above the image.

Have a look at the example:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #D0FEFE;
  margin: 30px 50px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.main-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.1rem;

}

.main-nav img {
width: 250px;
}


.box{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block; /* Make the width of box same as image */
}

.textbox{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0; 
        text-align: center;       
        top: 40%; /* Adjust this value to move the positioned div up and down */
        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
        color: white;
        width: 60%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
}
```

```html
   <div class="container">
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <div class="box">
                 <li>
                     <img src="https://d3s5n6bbhxr3im.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1d-1030x786.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="textbox">
                      <b>Home</b>
                     </div>
     </li>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                 <li>
                     <img src="https://d3s5n6bbhxr3im.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1d-1030x786.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="textbox">
                      <b>About</b>
                     </div>
     </li>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                 <li>
                     <img src="https://d3s5n6bbhxr3im.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1d-1030x786.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="textbox">
                      <b>Services</b>
                     </div>
     </li>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                 <li>
                     <img src="https://d3s5n6bbhxr3im.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1d-1030x786.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="textbox">
                      <b>Contact</b>
                     </div>
     </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

I hope the example is as you imagined it

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Why do you use <b> istead of <p>?

Comment: `<b>` make the text big (bold). But you can also take `<p>`